# How do I escape a forward slash '/' in JavaScript to query lucene?

Tags: javascript, regex, lucene

When I try this:

```
'cable/agency'.replace(/\//, '\/');
```

I get:

```
'cable/agency'
```

If I try this:

```
'cable/agency'.replace(/\//, '\\/');
```

or this:

```
'cable/agency'.replace(/\//, '\\\/');
```

I get this:

```
processedString cable\/agency
FilterTypes.js:51 processedString cable\\/agency
FilterTypes.js:51 processedString cable\\\/agency
FilterTypes.js:51 processedString cable\\\\/agency
FilterTypes.js:51 processedString cable\\\\\/agency
FilterTypes.js:51 processedString cable\\\\\\/agency
```

etc, until it exceeds the call stack.

Comment: What are you encoding it for? Is the value supposed to go in a URL?

Comment: You know, I'm not exactly sure. We are using websockets, so I think it's going over that. It shouldn't make a difference re: the question, as I want to convert `cable/agency` -> `cable\/agency` before it gets to Lucene.

Comment: Well, different data transports or contexts require different encoding. E.g. to escape a `"` in a JavaScript string literal requires `\"`. To encode it in an HTML attribute, you need to write `&quot;`. ``\`` is not an escape character in HTML. Similarly, to encode `/` in a URL, it has to be `%2F`. ``\`` is not an escape character in a URL either. Context matters. `'cable/agency'.replace(/\//, '\\/');` would be correct, but since it doesn't seem to work for you at another end, it might have to be escaped / encoded differently.

Comment: I have tested it. If I send over `cable\/agency` it works correctly. I just need to escape that forward slash.

Comment: `'cable/agency'.replace(/\//, '\\/');` is the way to go then. Don't know what else is done to the string that leads to infinite recursion.

Comment: That works if I run it in console, but it doesn't work from my code. When I output to console from my code it doesn't escape the forward slash.There is nothing else going on with the search and replace that should affect it.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with our codebase. Tnx for your help.